# Using the Beyond20 extension, how can I roll from my D&D Beyond character sheet in Roll20?

Tags: dnd-5e, online-resources, roll20, dnd-beyond

I recently discovered the Beyond20 browser extension and have installed it. The extension is supposed to make it so you can "roll" from your DNDbeyond character sheet and it will do the roll in your VTT (Roll20 for me.)

I've verified that my Roll20 character sheet is the "D&D 5e by Roll20" sheet that it uses, but any time I click on a roll in D&D Beyond?, it doesn't roll in Roll20.

Is there something I'm missing or a step where the Roll20 token is linked to my D&D Beyond character sheet? I'd really like to not track two character sheets, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I believe there's something to tell it which VTT you're using in the extension settings? I'm not sure but if there's no answer by then I can check when I get home and post an answer.

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami You can either select a specific one, or it'll just go to whatever is open. I've tried both.

Comment: Ah, well like I said, if there's no answer by the time I leave work I'll check then for you.

Comment: Do you have D&D Beyond's new dice roller functionality enabled or disabled? It is enabled by default.

Comment: @mdrichey  It is currently enabled

Comment: You should edit those clarifications into the question :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D&D Beyond's new digital dice roller interferes with Beyond20. Disable the dice roller and you should be good to go. To disable the dice roller, click the drop-down arrow next to your character's name when you are viewing your character sheet. You will see a toggle to enable/disable.

Source: Reports on D&D Beyond [forums](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/d-d-beyond-feedback/digital-dice-feedback/66107-issues-using-beyond-20-extension-and-alpha-dice) and my own testing.